# how can I update the values of sub collection and also values of collection in fire base, I attached image below for ref

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image][[image: 1st image2nd image]

I want to update the values in course collection[course] and also sub collection[sem], I stored the all values of [sem] subcollection in a list.
I don't know how to update the values

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much details… Neither on the `sem` subcollection (Does it have several documents? Or only one? In the second case do you know the id of the unique doc?) nor on the values you want to save (same fields for parent and children docs?).

So here is a generic answer, based on a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=en&authuser=2#batched-writes), and in which we queries all the docs of the `sem` subcollection in order to get their references:

```
// Get a new write batch
final batch = db.batch();

var parentRef = db.collection("cicourseties").doc("ZesQ7....");
batch.set(parentRef, { "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo" });

var childrenQuerySnapshot = await parentRef.collection("sem").get();

for (var docSnapshot in childrenQuerySnapshot.docs) {
    var childRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
    batch.update(docSnapshot.reference, { "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo" });
}

// Commit the batch
await batch.commit();
```

Comment: yes sem sub collection has several documents and I know the id...I have added one more image that showing details of sub collection.. please check it now

Comment: So the code in my answer is the one corresponding to your case. Just replace the payloads (i.e. `{ "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo" }`) with the desired JS objects and you’ll be ok!

Comment: Is this code work in flutter dart, I am sorry that I haven't mentioned it before that am building app in flutter dart

Comment: Yes it does. Did you try it?